# What are low-tech mock-ups? and how they can be designed?

Tags: mobile-application, mockup

In app development what are low-tech mock-ups? How they look exactly? and what tools are used to design them? Is it the same tools used in app development? or are there specific ones?

Comment: In collaborative design there’s a lot of mock ups done with pen and paper or on whiteboards. I would call those low-tech.

Comment: @Andy For example, does this mean I have to create an app? or not? I mean low tech mock up.

Comment: Would you have some sources of where this expression comes from? In which context is it used exactly? Are we talking mock-ups for low-tech solutions? Or are the mock-ups themselves realised with low-tech? Which word needs clarification? Low-tech or mock-up? Before we had Figma and other, digital prototyping tools, we created paper prototypes for apps and ran usability tests with those. Mock-ups in general can be done for all sorts of solutions, not only apps.

Comment: This is a complex issue. There are many tool options, and groups, organizations, users, designers are all unique and have different perspectives, tolerances, and expectations. Start with as low tech as possible, create some simple designs, and start showing them to people in these various groups and see if it's making sense to them. If not step up the tech a notch and try again. Over time I expect an effective workflow will develop.